# Identity for divergence of vector product

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm reviewing this paper and they state the following "vector identity":

$ \nabla \cdot (\textbf{u}\textbf{v}) = \nabla \textbf{u} \cdot \textbf{v} + (\nabla \cdot \textbf{v})\textbf{u}$

I tried to find some material online about this identity but didn't have any luck. I'm pretty sure $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are both vectors, as they're both bold face in the paper. Can someone help to provide more information on this identity? Is it valid? Can you give the proof?

EDIT

After some discussion, it seems that $\textbf{u}$ should be interpreted as a scalar (remove boldface), not a vector. I will clarify this with the original source and follow up if there is any further amendments. If it is a scalar, the answer below is correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Vector_dot_product

Comment: Which one are you referring to? It's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Vector dot product

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how that is the same identity I placed in the question. Can you show me how the two are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, fundamentally, just another case of the product rule for derivatives.

For the notation to make sense ($\nabla u$ and $\nabla\cdot v$ defined), $u$ should be a scalar-valued function of a vector variable, and $v$ should be a vector-valued function of that variable. Then $\nabla u$ is the gradient of $u$, and $\nabla\cdot v$ is the divergence of $v$. The two terms on the right are both scalars - the first is the dot product of the vector-valued gradient of $u$ and the vector-valued function $v$, while the second is the product of the scalar-valued divergence of $v$ and the scalar-valued function $u$.

To prove it, we just go down to components. I'll assume three dimensions here, although it works in more generality (Let $A,B,C$ be the components of $v$; $v(x,y,z)=(A(x,y,z),B(x,y,z),C(x,y,z))$):
\begin{align*}\nabla\cdot (uv)\quad &?\quad \nabla u\cdot v + (\nabla\cdot v) u\\
\frac{\partial (uA)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial (uB)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial (uC)}{\partial z}\quad &?\quad \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)\cdot (A,B,C) + \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial C}{\partial z}\right)u\\
u\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}+A\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+u\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}+B\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+u\frac{\partial C}{\partial z}+C\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} &= A\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+B\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+C\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+u\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}+u\frac{\partial B}{\partial y}+u\frac{\partial C}{\partial z} \end{align*}
Not too bad there. It's just all the same terms rearranged a bit.

There's another way to look at this. If you go on with mathematics long enough, you'll encounter the language of manifolds and differential forms, which provides a unifying framework for all of these vector calculus notions. In particular, both the gradient and the divergence are examples of the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), and the exterior derivative has a product rule. Here, working in $n$ dimensions, we have $u$ as a $0$-form and $v$ as an $(n-1)$-form. The gradient takes $0$-forms to $1$-forms, the divergence takes $(n-1)$-forms to $n$-forms, and the dot product between $1$-forms and $(n-1)$ forms is the wedge product, taking us to a $n$-form. Then we just apply the exterior derivative's product rule:
$$\nabla\cdot (uv) = d(u\wedge v) = du\wedge v + (-1)^0 u\wedge dv = \nabla u\cdot v + u(\nabla \cdot v)$$

Comment: Let me just clarify this part: "u should be a scalar-valued function of a vector variable, and v should be a vector-valued function of that variable"...are you saying that "u" must be a scalar and "v" must be a vector? That would imply that my interpretation of the paper notation is wrong (they use 2 bold letters, so I assumed they were both vectors).

Comment: Then you say "The two terms on the left are both scalars..."? Should say "right" not "left"?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation was wrong. $\nabla\cdot$ is the divergence, which applies to a vector. $\nabla$ without the dot is the gradient, which applies to a scalar. That's just what the standard notation means. Other comment - argh, directional dyslexia. I meant the right. Time to edit.

Comment: OK, I don't disagree with what you wrote, but I let me throw something at you. In the "material/total" derivative, you often see $(\textbf{u}\cdot \nabla) \textbf{v}$. I would read this as a vector, dotted with the gradient of a vector, which is a tensor 2? If I'm right in interpreting it this way, then the gradient operator doesn't necessarily operate on a scalar? I'm just worried that the author did intend that "u" and "v" be vectors.

Comment: What that notation reads as to me? A directional derivative. $u$ determines a direction by applying multipliers to the partial derivatives, and then we apply that to $v$. It's not the gradient operator at all; it takes a slice of $v$ as a function of one variable, and differentiates that.

Comment: "The formula for the vector Laplacian above may be used to avoid tensor math and may be shown to be equivalent to the divergence of the Jacobian matrix shown below for the gradient of a vector" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian). Here they state that the divergence can apply to a matrix and a gradient to vector. This contradicts your statement in the comment above, which seems to be the basis for you saying "Yes, your interpretation was wrong". Again, I'm just trying to make sure the identity in the question does not apply to "u" and "v" as vectors.

Comment: It might work out with a vector $u$ and a matrix $v$ - I haven't tried it to see if the details line up. But then, if we did, we wouldn't be writing the matrix product of $\nabla u$ and $v$ with a dot. In any case, $u$ and $v$ are not going to live in the same space as each other. It's also unlikely to be what was intended in the source you got this from, when there's a much simpler interpretation that definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), we can see it more easily:
$$
\nabla \cdot (u \textbf{v}) = \partial_i (uv_i) = \partial_iu \cdot v_i + u\cdot\partial_iv_i = \nabla u\cdot \textbf{v} + u(\nabla \cdot \textbf{v}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

For this to make sense $u$ is a scalar function and $\mathbf{v} = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a vector function.

We can calculate the partial derivatives using the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(u\mathbf{v})_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(uv_i) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}v_i + u\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Therefore, the Jacobi matrix is given by
$$\nabla(u\mathbf{v}) = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(u\mathbf{v})_i\right]_{1\le i,j\le n} = \left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}v_i + u\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\right]_{1\le i,j\le n} = \mathbf{v}\otimes (\nabla u) + u (\nabla\mathbf{v})$$

The divergence is obtained by taking the trace:

$$\nabla \cdot (u\mathbf{v}) = \operatorname{Tr}\left(\nabla(u\mathbf{v})\right) = \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{v}\otimes (\nabla u)) + u \operatorname{Tr}(\nabla\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{v}\cdot (\nabla u) + u(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v})$$